# Aura Component's <ltng:require> scripts not always loading

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error, static-resources, leaflet.js

I am trying to add some drawing capabilities to the [dreamhouse-lwc](https://github.com/trailheadapps/dreamhouse-lwc)'s auraPropertyListMap. The aura component uses the leaflet library, so I added the leaflet.draw plugin to the ltng:require. The leaflet.draw.js plugin is dependent on leaflet.js, so I add both of them to the ltnq:

```
<ltng:require
    styles="{!join(',' , $Resource.leaflet + '/leaflet.css' , $Resource.leaflet + '/leaflet.draw.css')}"
    scripts="{!join(',' , $Resource.leaflet + '/leaflet.js' , $Resource.leaflet + '/leaflet.draw.js')}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.handleJSLoaded}"
/>
```

In auraPropertyListMapRenderer.js, I add the drawing controls as the map is being made:

```
// Draw the map if it hasn't been drawn yet
    if (!component.map) {
        var mapElement = component.find('map').getElement();

        component.map = window.L.map(mapElement, {
            zoomControl: true,
            tap: false,
            dragging: true
            //drawControl: true
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-magic-numbers
        }).setView([42.356045, -71.08565], 13);
        component.map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
        var url =
            'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}';

        window.L.tileLayer(url).addTo(component.map);


        
        //Add drawing controls
        var drawnItems = new window.L.FeatureGroup();
        component.map.addLayer(drawnItems);
        //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR SOMETIMES HAPPENS
        try{
            var drawControl = new window.L.Control.Draw({
                edit: {
                    featureGroup: drawnItems
                }
            });
        }
        catch(error){
            console.error(error)
        }
        component.map.addControl(drawControl);
        
        
    }
```

On a hard refresh, the component appears to run normally, with the drawing controls visible. However, on normal refreshes, the drawControl will sometimes fail and throw the following error:

```
auraPropertyListMap.js:97 TypeError: window.L.Control.Draw is not a constructor
at rerender (auraPropertyListMap.js:90:35)
at G.Yd (aura_prod.js:420:136)
at TH.Yd (aura_prod.js:762:333)
at TH.Zr (aura_prod.js:776:204)
at rH (aura_prod.js:683:207)
at kH (aura_prod.js:682:165)
at b (aura_prod.js:675:107)
at mH (aura_prod.js:674:384)
at b (aura_prod.js:675:234)
```

The other aspects of the map still work properly, so this leads me to believe that the leaflet.draw.js plugin is not properly loaded all the time when it's functions get call. What could be the cause of this sporadic error?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you're correct in thinking that the leaflet.draw.js scripts haven't been loaded in time when that function is called.

To avoid this error, you can include an attribute in your component that is updated from a default value of false to true within the handleJSLoaded function. This can then be used in your renderer file to prevent the component from attempting to draw the map before all the required scripts are loaded.